# Can't get my mates to join my minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

My friends can't join my IP server. I've got it all set up, I gave them the right IP, but when they try to join, it simply says 'can't connect to server'. I've also gotten this error:

```
[01:25:05] [Server thread/WARN]: Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running 3281ms or 65 ticks behind
```

But I'm not sure if that's related to them joining. I'm on macOS, and when I use the IP to join my own server, it works just fine. Could someone help me out?

Comment: What hardware are you running the server on? That's essentially a message from the server saying it's trying its best but can't handle the load you're giving it. I got that message when running a server on my raspberry pi

Comment: I'm running the server on a macbook pro.

Comment: But what cpu are you using and how much memory is allocated? Also are you running your minecraft instance on the same computer?

Comment: For context, running a server on your laptop while you're also playing on it means that your laptop is doing double-duty as both a server and a client; that can be really taxing depending on the world and such, even if you've got reasonably powerful computer.

Comment: I had the same problem, when I used to use a Mac, even after port forwarding. I think I probably didn't configure the machine's firewall properly.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem is that you did not port forward the server. I know that it is necessary in order to allow your friends to join, but I myself have never done that, so I may not be able to help in port forwarding, but I can link a few tutorials to you which might help.

[How to setup a java 1.16.5 server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7or-3wnpmk).

[Port forwarding for any Minecraft version.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X75GbRaGzu8)

Also, to resolve your second issue, that is the message that says "server can't keep up, x ticks behind" means that you have not allocated enough ram to your server, due to which the server is experiencing lag. To fix this, the following links might help.

[Website link](https://www.meloncube.net/clients/knowledgebase/105/Minecraft-lag-types-and-how-to-fix-them.html) (non video tutorial)

[Video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xM8M13EVDeA) (video tutorial)

If you already port forwarded, but still your friends can't join, consider reporting to Mojang about this issue.
I hope this helped, if not, sorry.